# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] generating extra & in URL

Tags: php

Having an issue here where the

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

is spitting out:
 `/dev/nava2/store/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=48`

the actual URL is `/dev/nava2/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=48`

obviously, the difference being the `&amp;` on the top vs. the `&` on the bottom

full code looks like this:

```
$currentpage = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];  
$classic = "/dev/nava2/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=48";


if ($currentpage == $classic) 
    { $classicclass = "current";

    } 

else { echo "";}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&amp;` is the html entity corresponding to `&`. You can obtain to original string back with [html_entity_decode](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) :

```
$original = html_entity_decode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: And url should NOT contain `&` but `&amp;`, however most browsers/web servers will put effort for correcting users input... see [w3c Appendix B: §B.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo html_entity_decode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: this wont work, according to http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php urldecode only decode %## encodings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [html_entity_decode()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) to get the actual url but the top one should work. I dont think you need to change anything. You could also use str_replace or preg_replace if you really need to change some parts of your uri.